# SQLAlchemy doesn't create tables in a Flask application

Tags: python, sqlite, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I've been trying to create a first web application using Flask. The problem is I can't get around creating the database.db file, or even the tables within the database, when the file already exists using create_all() function.

Here's my init module:

```py
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from os import path

db = SQLAlchemy()
DB_NAME = "database.db"

def create_app():
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config\["SECRET_KEY"\] = "yfytf345fg34y5t"
app.config\['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'\] = f'sqlite:///{DB_NAME}'
db.init_app(app)

    from .views import views
    from .auth import auth
    
    app.register_blueprint(views, url_prefix='/')
    app.register_blueprint(auth, url_prefix='/')
    
    with app.app_context():
        from .models import Note, User
        db.create_all()
        db.session.commit()
    
    return app
```

And here are the models created:

```py
from . import db
from flask_login import UserMixin
from sqlalchemy.sql import func

class Note(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    data = db.Column(db.String(10000))
    date = db.Column(db.DateTime(timezone=True), default=func.now())
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))

class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(150), unique=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(150))
    firstName = db.Column(db.String(150))
    notes = db.relationship('Note')
```

I've been following a 3-year old youtube tutorial on flask, I accounted for changes in SQLAlchemy docummentation, used app context and basically went through all of the recent similar questions asked, but got no solution.

Comment: The question I would ask is, does `db.create_all()` get called before or after the model definition code is executed?  If before, then the models will not have been registered, so won't be created.

Comment: I import Note and User before executing db_create_all(), also there is nothing to execute in the models, it's just the declaration, and if there was something wrong with it, importing the classes would throw an error. At least this is my thinking atm.

Comment: Why do you have `\[` and `\]` with `app.config` ? And also why are the 4 lines from `app = ...` to `db.init_app(app)` not indented ?

Comment: @mwdziak if I fix the indentation errors and escaped square bracked (as well as removing the auth/login since I do not have it installed right now), I can run the app and it created the SQLite DB file.